# How can I show/hide the status bar on a pageViewController using tap gesture (iOS8 / Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, statusbar, uipageviewcontroller

Looking through all the solutions given to similar questions, I have been trying to get the `statusBar` to show/hide with a tap gesture.

I have set `View controller-based status bar appearance = NO` in the plist.

I have tried the following code in my `DataViewController` (page view controller) AND in the `RootViewController`:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
app.setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
```

and it doesn't work.

This is embedded in a `UITabBarController`, would that make a difference?

Also, I was able to get the following to hide the statusBar from the `RootViewController`:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

But the `DataViewController` does not even call this function, and was only able to hide it permanently this way, rather than toggle it on/off.

Any ideas?

Comment: That should work—are you sure the method that calls `setStatusBarHidden` is being called?

Comment: breakpoint gets hit there, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried it in code, everything works fine for me. Make sure that the `View controller-based status bar appearance` is Set to **NO**. And there is no needs to override `prefersStatusBarHidden()`.

Comment: I want to be able to show/hide the status bar on a tap gesture, won't this simply hide it altogether?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. I have tried in my code, and everything works fine. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: where are you calling this? in DataViewController? or RootViewController?

Answer (score 0):

if you using `UIPageViewController` then you should use this code in the `RootViewController`

if you have a `navigationController` it will hide it too

on `ViewDidLoad()`

`self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true`

and use this method to hide or show the status Bar based on if the `navigationBar` is hidden or not

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        if self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == true {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
   }
```